# Use terms from text file in SQL WHERE ... IN clause

Tags: sql, mysql, file, where-clause

I'm running SQL query for MySQL server with

```
...
where name in ("term1","term2","term3")
```

I would like to get the list of terms from a text file with one term per line. How can I do this?

What about if this list of terms will get large? 10K, for example. Will this be efficient or I should use another approach? May be temporary table and join? The database is read-only.

Comment: do you have php or perl?  both would work nicely with this and a little nested loop madness

Comment: Perl would be fine. Would you show an example piece of code as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not so familiar with MySQL but I see something like this where you can load a text file in a table as you suggested in your question:-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, column2, column3);
```

and then use joins for getting data.

Details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I have to create t1 table first, right? Can I do it, if the database is read-only?

Comment: In SQL server, you could create the table in a different database and read from the other (read-only) database using the DatabaseName..TableName notation. I am not very sure if this is possible in MySQL. Should be possible there as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this public MySQL server does not give permissions to create neither temp table or database.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! I just wanted to accept this question not to leave it unanswered. Since all questions were about the same and about at the same time, I accepted this one for code example and link to details.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using a `WHERE ... IN` statement gets very slow after a couple of hundred/thousand terms.

Also, if the table is read-only, then you won't be able to add indexes to make it any faster, so, like astander said, I would suggest a temporary table with a join.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet might be to read this into a *temp table/ table used specifically for this look up*.

This way you can index the table, and use an **inner join/ where in sub query**.